# Why is the solubility of calcium sulfate so low even though it is a salt?

Tags: aqueous-solution, solubility

What is the reason the solubility of calcium sulfate in water is so low? Compared to other salts like potassium sulfate (110 g/L) or calcium nitrate (1470 g/L) the solubility of calcium sulfate seems to be very low (2.4 g/L).

Comment: Being a salt doesn't mean it has to be soluble

Comment: That's a pretty good equivalent of _"Why is Donald Trump so poor, even though he is American?"_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solubility of calcium sulphate is quite high, compared to many much less soluble salts, like barium sulphate, calcium phosphate or calcium fluoride.

Most of insoluble minerals are salts.

Insoluble/limited solubility salts have as crystals lower [Gibbs energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_free_energy) than dissolved, leading to solution being thermodynamically  unfavourable.

That is related to mutual relation of energy of crystal lattice and of hydration of ions, and also to dissolution [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy) change.

Comment: @ Poutnik. You are right. But the question should be rewritten so : How to explain why insoluble salts have as crystals a lower Gibbs energy than dissolved ?

Comment: There is a similar situation with halogenides. Calcium iodide, bromide and chloride are extremely soluble in water. Surprisingly, Calcium fluoride is absolutely insoluble in water. Why ?

Comment: Only if the opposite has to be explained as well, i.e.why soluble salts have lower G if dissolved. :-)